# UITableView is missing on rotation of device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, landscape-portrait

I have a `UITableView` and `UIImageView` in `UIViewController`.
When I rotate my app to landscape `UITableView` is *missing* and am not able to see it.

I am not doing anything for handling the rotation yet using the Auto layout.

Shall I need to handle rotation manually? Please suggest.